# Examples of evolving networks in Space Exploration

Tags: deep-space-network

I'm a master student working on networks analysis in general. A network is something that has nodes and there are links between the nodes. Nodes and links could have attributes. An evolving network is one that changes overtime (new nodes and links are added..etc). An example of that is Facebook. Nodes are users and links represent the friendship relationship. Users have attributes (gender, age ..etc). A Facebook network as you know is an example of a social network.

The issue is that so many people studied traditional evolving networks like social networks, the web, or transportation networks. Currently I'm looking for novel examples of evolving networks to study them. So I thought there might be some examples or applications in *Space Exploration* that could represent some kind of an evolving network.

So my question: Can you give me examples in *Space Exploration* for evolving networks?

Comment: A copy-paste cross-site question...

Comment: Flagged for mods' attention, posted [a question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232277/asking-essentially-the-same-question-across-multiple-sites-with-site-name-subst).

Comment: Marking this as too broad. Please decide where on [se] you'd like to ask your question and include specifics that would help us identify what in particular are you interested in. Cross-posting a generic question on multiple sites is not contributing towards our requirement for specificity and prior research as described in our [Ask]. This goes the same for any and all [SE] sites. Thanks!

Comment: But.. isn't that doing research? By asking the question, this person is looking for answers. It doesn't seem to be malicious at all; maybe this person has learned that Stack Exchange is a really good place to learn new information. More fitting would be if they could ask this question to a network or complex systems type of forum, and I know that a couple have been proposed in Area51, namely [Network Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61500/network-science) and [Complex Systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63090/complex-systems).

Comment: @Stu It's a list question, which are frowned upon throughout [SE] as it is, especially if there's many possible answers. But more importantly, it's non-specific with no identification what would constitute a helpful answer. [Evolving networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolving_networks) can be anything, from artificial neural networks (AI), communications networks, to social networks, career paths, transportation routes, you name it. That's why I opted for "too broad", but "primarily opinion based" equally applies. Also, it now has two answers, can you tell which one answers it better?

Comment: Alright, I see the issue now. Thanks for clarifying! A better question would be "Is ______ an evolving network?" and list some of the various characteristics of "_____", although even that question still doesn't have a good fit anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few examples.

The best example is at Mars. New orbiting spacecraft arrive on a regular basis, which usually have a relay instrument to relay back information from landing probes to Earth. As new probes land, or new orbiting spacecraft arrive, then the number nodes changes. There are plans to more formalize the protocol. The current plan is to call it the [Interplanetary Internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_Internet).

Closer to home, new satellites for constellations such as GPS, Irridium, GlobalStar, and Orbcomm are added. Irridium in particular will talk with one satellite to another, the others will just add functionality when new satellites are launched.

Comment: Along with considering the orbiting spacecraft, also consider the receiving stations on the ground.

Comment: can you please make it a bit more detailed? like what are nodes here and what do the links between the nodes represent? Also is it possible to construct a dataset from that so I can study the data?

Comment: @AlexTwain Would you please be more specific and describe in more detail, preferably in your question, what information you're hoping to find? What data would you like to study? For Mars, there's e.g. [Mars Orbital Data Explorer](http://ode.rsl.wustl.edu/mars/indexMapSearch.aspx) that's freely available for anyone to study datasets from Mars orbiters, past and present. Similar datasets are available for missions to other planets, their moons and the Sun (e.g. [SDO](http://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/), [STEREO](http://stereo.gsfc.nasa.gov/),...).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an explanation of space debris from a networks perspective.

A collection of nodes with properties who are connected (in proximity) with other nodes whose properties are similar. If two nodes coincide in a specific collection of time dependent properties (say position in x, y and z but not attitude) then the result is the removal of these nodes and the introduction of a new collection of nodes that have similar properties to the parent nodes. Also you have the arbitrary addition of nodes (launching new objects) and the eventual subtraction of nodes based on a time that is a function of the nodes properties (atmospheric drag de-orbiting and re-entry).

Quite close to evolutionary networks I think.

EDIT:

In fact I remembered a paper I read a few months back about this very topic:

[A new analysis of debris mitigation and removal using networks](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0094576509003191)

This might get you well on your way to your lit review, or even the outlines of your model! :D